# PHP: Facebook / Twitter Integration

Tags: php, facebook, twitter, social-networking

I have a CMS built in php and I'm looking to add Social Networking integration to it. I basicaly want to pre-populate the comments and contact us forms with the Facebook/Twitter information of the visitor if it's available.

Is there something reliable already built and tested or should I start from scratch?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the solutions that's getting pretty popular is DISQUS.com, it allows users to comment when they're logged into Facebook/Twitter and many other sites. And it's starting to get wide adoption.

Comment: This is not a perfect solution, but it'll work for most people. Finding this out after weeks of experience on a site that receives a good amount of traffic.

Answer (score 1):

You can integrate Facebook's [Comments social plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments) into your site. That would be quick and very reliable. :)